# Too many values to unpack when using python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to use dictionary to edit a file combining multiple lines that have the same pattern on the right side of a delimiter ":".  The function works fine when small file is passed to it.  But when a large file is passed to it I get "too many values to unpack" error.  I then get the same error when passing the previously working small file.  I'm assuming I'm not releasing resources or exhausting some buffer somewhere.  I appreciate any help I can get.

```
def line_combine_list(x):
  x_file = open(x, 'r')
  file_out = open('Result', 'w')
  d = defaultdict(list)
  for line in x_file:
     l, val = line.split(':')  ####this is where the error shows
     d[val.strip()].append(l.strip()) 
  x_file.close()
  for key in d:
     file_out.write(','.join(d[key]) + ':' + key + '\n')
  file_out.close()
```

Comment: Because at some point `line.split(':')` is returning a list with more than two elements. This doesn't have anything to do with the dictionary. Have you tried printing the offending `line` to *see* what's going on? That'll probably be revealing.

Comment: It's not related to dictionary , it's about split line , maybe in some lines there are more than one `:` and then your list have more than 2 values.

Comment: Thank you greatly for your help.  I will fix the file accordingly.

Comment: You might want to inspect how exactly the lines making trouble look. Adapting your code to account for these exceptions could potentially be a better solution than to manually fix the lines.